# NancyFx. Forms authorization. Ajax and unauthorized response

Tags: ajax, wcf, forms-authentication, nancy

I use wcf-hosted NancyFx with forms authorization with redirection enabled (DisableRedirect = false). 
I would like in case of unsuccesfull authorization attempt handle it and signal to user (show some tooltip that user name or password is wrong). How can I do it with FormAuth?

Another approach is to use Ajax post request, but because of redirection I can't get 401 code. If I turn off redirection it works (I can get 401 in ajax post request). But I want to use redirection facilities in my application...

I never work before with FormAuth, so what is my options here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NancyFx RequiresAuthentication extension returns 303 and not 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212140/nancyfx-requiresauthentication-extension-returns-303-and-not-403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually there were obvious solution based on parsing returned querystring (smth like login?error=true&username=a, as in examples for Nancy forms auth app). On document load parse this query string and show tooltip... Another question whether it is standart (good) practise?..